How do I completely turn of JPG compression in Magento 2.4.3?
I optimized my product images in media/catalog/product directory(not the images in cache folder).
I flushed the catalog images cached and the magento cache and afer that the cached image becomes larger in size(KB/MB) than the original.
I know that this is related to Magento image compression, but how can I completely turn of JPG compression in Magento 2.4.3?
And just as a note if I set "Media Gallery Image Optimization" in Configurations > Advanced > System to "Enable Image Optimization = No" do not help
also in "Images Upload Configuration" to set to Quality = 100 and Enable Frontend Resize = No don´t work.
Many thanks to anyone who can give me a hint about this.
